# How to rewrite js code in ejs

Tags: javascript, html, file, variables, ejs

I have written this code in js, but I need to rewrite it in ejs because it can't be seen by the user after the page is loaded. This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/showads.js" class="deleteMe"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" class="deleteMe">
  if(window.canRunAds == undefined){
    window.location = "/welcome";
  }
  $('.deleteMe').remove();
</script>
```

I have this file named showads.js that contains a canRunAds variable. If the client has adblock enabled this file won't be imported, making the canRunAds variable undefined, and if is the client will be redirected to '/welcome', and then I just delete those 2 scripts, but it doesn't work, because the client can see it and maybe bypass it. Is there a way to write this in ejs, because when I tried it, I got an error saying window is undefined. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but what you're trying to do is impossible. The code you're trying to hide is purely a client side task so you can't run it on the server.

Comment: @Juhana Isn't ejs a client side language? You can write: <% if(true){ %>
<h1>Hi</hi>
<% } %> And this will run. This also works if you have a server-sent variable!

Comment: It is client-side if you run it on the client. But then the code is on the client and the client can read, modify and bypass it at will, so it won't solve the problem.

Comment: @Juhana Ok then, is there another way to do it? That or check to see if the user has adblock directly!

Comment: Like I already said, it's impossible. The user has full control over their computer.

Answer (score -1):

It's true that you can run `ejs` in the client side without any server ( node.js ) but you can't access the `DOM` with it ( like you're doing now with JQuery ), so i assume all what you can parse to `EJS` 
is :

```
<%
if(window.canRunAds == undefined){
    window.location = "/welcome";
  }
%>
```

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript on the server doesn't have a `window` object. What can be done however is check that the `window` object is available at runtime, and conditionally run your code if it's accessible:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/showads.js" class="deleteMe"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" class="deleteMe">

  // Check if window exists, and that canRunAds doesn't
  // On the server, the code within this block should never run
  if(window && !window.canRunAds){
    window.location = "/welcome";
  }
  // Bonus points using the same principle: Avoid assuming jQuery is available in
  // inline script blocks.
  if(window && window.jQuery) { 
    $('.deleteMe').remove(); 
  }
</script>
```

Note that if your `showads.js` script is being run on the server, you'd also have to wrap any call to `window` in an `if()` check, otherwise the server will continue to throw an error.

Comment: The only thing in showads.js is this line: `var canRunAdds = true;`. jQuery is imported before this script, but that doesn't solve the problem, because if they press CTRL + U on the page running it, they can see it. I want to hide it permanently!

Comment: Firstly, if you're just setting a variable and not adding to the `window` object in `showads.js`, you're code will never work anyway. Secondly, all code and material that's served to a user should be considered viewed. If a user wants to dive in and check your code out, they just need to view the source of the page that was served, because you used an inline script block that's part of the document.

Comment: The code that I have now works as it should, it **does** detect adblock. The way I want to write it with ejs doesn't work!

Comment: I think you maybe need pay heed to what @Juhana has already said. Yes, it's possible to delete script nodes on the client after they run for vanity's sake and avoid doing window calls accidently if your code runs on the server, but I think what you're trying to achieve is running code on a client without the client even being able to be aware it's being run, which just isn't possible. EJS is just a templating language that can render html pages by plugging in the results of JavaScript methods and variables. It might be best to revisit the whiteboard on your intentions and tone.